# How to load the entire (or more of the) DOM for inifinite scrolling page that uses Ajax?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

If you look at a page like this: http://www.fieg.nl/ias-demo#/

You can see that it uses Ajax to dynamically add content when you scroll to the bottom, similar to how Google Images works.

If there was a page like this that I wanted to capture for parsing, I would do something like:

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.fieg.nl/ias-demo#/");
```

But this only gets everything that initially loads before any Ajax happens. Is it possible to use PHP or CURL or any other programs to capture the entire page and automatically load the Ajax content and capture that as well?

Also if there happens to be a weird page where it never stops loading things and literally goes on forever, I'm not sure how the tool would have to handle that. Because the tool would never find the end of the DOM in that situation.

Comment: I imagine you'd want to capture that AJAX call and manually replicate it.  Then just adjust the parameters of the call and repeat as many times as you'd like.  This would probably have to be tailored to each site for which you'd want to do this, I doubt they all use the same pattern (even if many of them use a similar plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Those pages work by sending an ajax request to fetch more data as the user scrolls towards the bottom of a page. The javascript then writes the response of the ajax request into the bottom of the page.

You need to run a tool like firebug to analyse the requests that are made to the server to retrieve the next page of content (using the net panel). Once you have found out the request URL, you need to emulate these requests in your PHP script.

Unfortunately SO is not the place for people to write your scripts to spider websites, but there is the theory anyway.